# javascript: get access to objects in different frame?

Tags: javascript

if I have 2 frames of a frameset on 1 page, is there a way for JS to access elements from the opposite frame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but only if pages on both frames is on the same domain. You can do `document.getElementById( "frame_id").contentWindow.document`... But still if pages are on different domain you will get an exception.
PS. You can read more [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/)

Comment: Thanks, how do you access it...just like normal?

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this
parent.framename.attributes_to_change

Check this site for a full blown example
http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jframe1.htm