# Access elements in one frameset from other frameset

Tags: javascript, html, frames

I have a html page in which I have two framesets each pointing to different html.

Now let's say, I have a textbox in first frameset (html) and a button in my second frameset (html).

Could anyone please let me know how to hide textbox when I click the button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: get access to objects in different frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987423/javascript-get-access-to-objects-in-different-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested, but it should be like this (in the onclick-handler of your button):

```
parent.frames[1].document.getElementByid('mytextfield').style.display = 'hidden';
//           ^^^ here you could also access the frame by its name using ['mysecondframe']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do all of the above only if the two frames are in the same domain.  Due to browsers [security policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), if the frames aren't on the same domain and even on the same protocol, they cannot interact with each other ( javascript is out of the question ).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the element via the `getElementById` function on the `document` object of the frame in question (note that we use the target frame's `document`, not our own). You can get the frame from the frameset by name — frame names become properties of the frameset's `window` object.

Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/opese3); [button frame code](http://jsbin.com/udere4/edit)):

```
var textbox = parent.targetFrame.document.getElementById('theTextBox');
textbox.value = "You clicked at " + new Date();
```

...where `targetFrame` is the name of the target frame. You can also use `frames[n]` where `n` is the index of the frame in the frameset, but I find names more robust.

The above example is tested and works on Firefox, Chrome, and Opera for Linux and IE6 — and so should work on a broad set of browsers.