# XPATH of framesets

Tags: javascript, python, html, xpath

I have a page that has two frames side by side.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  ..various scripts..
  </HEAD> 
    <FRAMESET framespacing="0" border="2" rows="93,*,0" frameborder=0>
      <FRAME scrolling=no noresize SRC="title_new_2.asp" NAME=titleFrm id=titleFrm>
        <FRAMESET framespacing="5" border="5" cols="51%,*" name="cjSet" id="cjSet" frameborder=1>   
          <FRAME SRC="../project/search/project_search.aspx" NAME=left scrolling="auto" frameborder=0>
          <FRAME SRC="dashboard.aspx?demo=n" NAME=right scrolling="auto" frameborder=0>
        </FRAMESET>
     <FRAME src="blank.htm" border=0 noresize frameborder=0  scrolling=no framespacing=0 NAME=tcj>
   </FRAMESET>    
</HTML>
```

I'm trying to get some data that's contained in the frame name=left with the project_search.aspx URL. I've tried both of the below and neither seem to work.

```
/html/frameset/frameset/frame

//*[@id="cjSet"]/frame[1]
```

Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: That xpath should get you the <frame> element pointing to that project_search URL, but it can't access the contents of that url. If javascript in the browser, then see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987423/javascript-get-access-to-objects-in-different-frame     If python, then you need to join that @src attribute to the base url and download that resource separately.

Comment: Depends on the environment (e.g., are you using and html or xml parser), but you may need to use upper case FRAME. Also, with a big 'depends' you might be able to use GetElementById or some variant as 'id' may be indexed.

Comment: @StevenD.Majewski Thanks.  It seems very likely that I will have to parse those SRC pages individually since the data seems nowhere to be found.